# How to run .jar files with Sun Java 6?

Tags: command-line, java, minecraft

I cannot seem to open Minecraft.jar from the file browser. Everytime I try, I select open with, then Sun Java and nothing happens. I've tried the terminal too, but that fails and just reports a load of errors. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please post the errors. Are you sure you have java?

Comment: What's your output when you do `sudo java -version`?

Answer (score 3):

go to the folder with the .jar file.

type: `java -jar filename.jar` in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Issue

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

to see, what Java versions are installed. Often there is more than one.

```
update-java-alternatives -h
```

to get more help, specify your prefered version with

```
update-java-alternatives -s VERSION_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install java run time and you can run with micro emulator. You can consult the following post:
http://callthetricks.com/3375/jar-file-ubuntu/